# Windows Azure Mobile Services: Authentication

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm using WAMS: Microsoft authentication.

At the current time I Have 2 Windows Store applications which use WAMS MS authentication. You know that WAMS returns you a "userID" which is like 'dcasdasdcasdcasdcad12ecqwecsacd' and etc. And this "userId" is different in both of my 2 applications.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this is id generated by WAMS(+ my MS account) for my application
   or it is id of my MS account?
2. Will it change in one application?
3. Can I use it as a PK in my Users table?
4. What can I do with this "userId", can I get user name or user contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for question 1: I think that this application generate a key from the combination between the user id and the application id.

for question 2: no the id will not change in the same application I just want to add the question 3 answer to this one is that you can add the users to the tables you have and make their ID as Primary key.  After all these tables in WAMS are stored in Windows Azure SQL Database.  have a look on the following tutorial.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/authorize-users-in-scripts-dotnet/

for the last question: you will have to work with the SDK for the platform you are getting the identity from.  in the following tutorial you can find that he installed the Live SDK to work with the authentication for the windows application

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-dotnet/

I hope that this helps let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As for question 4, you can discover more information about the user provided that they give consent for you to access their information.

You can find out more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826534.aspx